# Android - How to check current device owner?

Tags: android, adb, device-owner

Assuming I've got rooted device I am able to set device owner by adb:

```
dpm set-device-owner xxx.package.xxx
```

So - is there any possibility to check current device owner using adb? 
Now I have to disable single app mode and go to security settings which isn't best way regarding multiple devices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44843781/1778421