# How to check if an Android App is a device owner?

Tags: android, adb, robotframework

I am executing one test case using robot framework where I have to install an app and make it as device owner and then check if the same app has become a device owner or not. I have searched though Stack Overflow and other search engine results but there, they have mentioned on how to make an app as device owner but not the way how to check if an app is a device owner.

I have used following command to make my app as device owner :

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.myapp.package/.main.receiver.DeviceAdminReceiver
```

Now, I wanted to validate whether it is a device owner or now using ADB command.

Comment: do `adb shell cat /data/system/device_owner.xml` before and after your `dpm` command

Comment: also there is `dumpsys device_policy`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`adb shell dumpsys device_policy`

This command will give you a bunch of policies including the device owner (it's the first policy) with the package name and the corresponding receiver.

To make it easier to check it use `adb shell dumpsys device_policy | grep "admin"`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. While `adb shell getprop ro.device_owner` can be used to determine if Device Owner mode is on, the above command was successful in showing the component name of the MDM application on my tablet that I am developing on. I was planning on using this with various `DevicePolicyManager` functions.

Comment: You could also run `adb shell "dumpsys device_policy | grep package"` to get just the package name of the device owner

Answer (score 4):

```
adb shell getprop ro.device_owner
```

returns `true` if device owner mode is enabled.

Comment: could you elaborate on your answer more to illustrate your approach?

Comment: the question was not about whether the mode was enabled or not but rather about checking which specific app is the device owner

Comment: This answer leads to wrong direction since OP wants to check if a component is device owner or not. But accepted answer is for detecting device owner mode status.

Comment: This answer looks correct, but some more explanation is needed. We know that only one Android app can be set as the device owner app at any time. So first, make sure the above command returns “false”. Then set your Android app as the device owner app. Then run the above command again. If the answer is “true”, your app has been successfully set as the device owner app.

Comment: Not all android devices have the `ro.device_owner` property, in which case there will be no return value

Answer (score 1):

you need to interrogate the system and return A LOT of data. This is not feasible, however as a tip for others, you can use *"findstr"* **or** *"grep"* as a second command to search the results. Each line is a result, not an excerpt:
NOTE: A blank response means there was **NO match** of against Device-Owner / DeviceOwner APK installed.

```
> adb shell dumpsys device_policy | findstr "admin"

  admin=ComponentInfo{com.pdp.deviceowner/com.pdp.deviceowner.receivers.AdminReceiver}
    com.wtmp.svdsoftware/com.wtmp.core.admin.AdminReceiver:
        179: com.ms.office365admin

> adb shell "dumpsys device_policy | grep deviceowner"

  admin=ComponentInfo{com.pdp.deviceowner/com.pdp.deviceowner.receivers.AdminReceiver}
    package=com.pdp.deviceowner
    com.pdp.deviceowner/.receivers.AdminReceiver:
```

However, a **BETTER answer** would be to change the query:

```
> adb shell dumpsys device_policy | findstr "package="
> adb shell "dumpsys device_policy | grep package="

  package=com.pdp.deviceowner
```

*(just noticed [@Natfoli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843781/how-to-check-if-an-android-app-is-a-device-owner#comment124493877_66157371) mentioned similar answer.)*